# unqlite.h:651:15: error: changes meaning of ‘pgno’ from ‘typedef sxu64 pgno’ [-fpermissive]

Tags: linux, eclipse, gcc, unqlite

Just downloaded the *unqlite.c* and *unqlite.h*, created a new project in Eclipse, copied one of the examples from [unqlite.org](http://www.unqlite.org) website and I'm getting the following error:

```
21:37:51 **** Build of configuration Debug for project nosql ****
make all 
Building file: ../main.cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"
In file included from ../main.cpp:49:0:
../unqlite.h:661:8: error: declaration of ‘pgno unqlite_page::pgno’ [-fpermissive]
pgno pgno; /* Page number for this page */
^
../unqlite.h:651:15: error: changes meaning of ‘pgno’ from ‘typedef sxu64 pgno’ [-fpermissive]
typedef sxu64 pgno;
^
subdir.mk:25: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
21:37:51 Build Finished (took 171ms)
```

It was meant to be as simple, but I have no clue of what is going on... Has anyone tried this unqLite KV store?

I'm using

**gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)**

Cheers

ttkdroid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue appears when including unqlite.h in a C++ file, and compiling it with a g++. You have two solutions to fix it:

- You can get the patch produced by the author of the lib as indicated here: https://github.com/symisc/unqlite/issues/24
- Or you can edit the unqlite.h file on line 661 replacing:

`pgno pgno; /* Page number for this page */`

by

`::pgno pgno; /* Page number for this page */`

Which will work with a g++ compiler as well as other C++ compilers. Of course, you cannot compile unqlite.c with this edited header, with a C compiler.

If you want to learn more about this error, this might be a good link: [typedef changes meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187549/typedef-changes-meaning)

Have a good day!

Comment: You will have to do some efforts to get it working yes. Compile the C file with a C compiler, modify the above, and surround your include with extern 'C' { unqlite.h }. I believe this is all. See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039015/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbo-unqlite).